# Why does this expression equal pi?

Tags: approximation, pi

I was fiddling with numbers when I noticed that 
$$50 \times 1.05^{168} \times \frac{12600}{727767941} \approx \pi$$ 
I understand it's an approximation. Does anyone know why?

Comment: That's probably just a coincidence.

Comment: Ho many digits accuracy does it give you? That's a fairly random expression - given any huge numerator, we can likely find some denominator that gets somewhat close.

Comment: If you play with numbers hard enough, you can mold damn near anything into $\pi$.

Comment: I only possess a basic calculator, and I don't know how to write a computer code, so my calculator just says it equals pi. So i'm unsure as to what extent it equals pi.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Even so, I was wondering if there was a way to derive this. Or some geometric explanation for this.

Comment: It's definitely not exactly equal, because $\pi$ is transcendental, and thus irrational, and the expression is rational.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews of course that's why I said it was an approximation.

Comment: There are loads of expressions like this. Not sure what you mean by "derive."

Comment: @ThomasAndrews I guess I assumed there had to be a mathematical reason for an expression to approach a number other than just coincidence.

Comment: It does not "approach" $\pi$. It is very easy to find a single number that is close to $\pi$. It is harder to find a sequence that *approaches* $\pi$.

Comment: If you gave us a *reason* or something interesting about that denominator, then it might be worth exploring, or if these values came out of another question, but just blindly, a number close to $\pi$ is a dime a dozen - there are lots of them. There isn't a "reason" for it - there are lots of expressions equally close to every real number.

Comment: But in general, such a closeness doesn't require or usually have an explanation beyond the calculation that shows it is close. We explore such coincidences only when the expression is remarkably simple, or if there is something non-arbitrary-seeming about the values. Here, if you expressed your value as a fraction, it would have a huge denominator (since $1.05=\frac{21}{20}$.) That's actually considered a very bad approximation, because we can get $168$ digits accuracy with a denominator of $10^{168}$.

Comment: There are occasionally really incredible approximations of $\pi$. For example: $$\frac{\ln 262 537 412 640 768 744}{\sqrt{163}}$$ is unreasonably close, because there is a deep reason for $e^{\pi\sqrt{163}}$ to be remarkably close to an integer.

Comment: $262537412640768744=640320^3+744.$

Answer (score 8):

By my calculator this expression only agrees with $\pi$ to about 13 decimal digits. Since there are 22 separate digits in the expression, we should expect that very many *different* expressions of that shape approximate $\pi$ with a similar precision -- there's nothing particular remarkable about one of them, nor any "explanation" other than it just happens to be close to $\pi$.

Comment: Thanks. My calculator and my low coding abilities did not enable me to see to what extent it agrees with pi.

Comment: In fact, $1.05^{168}\times\frac{80034}{92454253}$ is a better approximation with fewer digits, but $\frac{80143857}{25510582}$ without the power of $1.05$ is even better.